# net beans Modules can't start

Tags: java, c++, c, netbeans

So I downloaded net beans C and C++ pack, and when I first opened it, it showed this warning message:

[image: error message]

It works, but I want to fix this problem because it might do some problems in bigger programs I will create.

I have also tried to go to the link that was in the warning message that I posted here, but I really did not understand anything in there so it didn't help at all.

So if anyone knows what the problem is, and how to fix it, please tell me.

Comment: it has been all said. install [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: thats says its for java developers... not C.

Comment: `So if anyone knows what the problem is, and how to fix it, please tell me.` for problems, there is none, to fix the message annoyment install jdk (or remove the plugin that uses it)

Comment: if ill uninstall the plugin that uses it, will it effect in any way the programm? if no, how do i uninstall it?

Comment: What do you mean "it works"? Can you edit/compile/link C++ programs in NetBeans?